# Access delegated hosts variable while include role

Tags: ansible

I've an inventory as follow:

```
[central]
central_1 
central_2

[peripheral]
peripheral_1
peripheral_2
...
```

`central_1` and `central_2` share the same database and each `peripheral_*` has its own local database.
Connection parameters are all stored in `group_vars/central.yml` and multiple `host_vars/peripheral_*` files.

Then I have a bunch of roles that access the database and perform specific operation based on values in `peripheral_conf` hostvars.

My goal here is to run a subset of the roles on one `central` host using the right DB access parameter.

---

**First attempt**

First attempt was to have two different play in the playbook targeting different hosts

```
- hosts: peripheral
  pre_tasks:

    - name: Load Configuration
      set_fact:
        peripheral_conf: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] }}"
  
  roles:
    - role1
    - role2
    - role3

- hosts: central
  roles:
    - role1
    - role2
```

but, since I normally run the playbook limiting the inventory to a specific peripheral host, I'm not able to run it against the central hosts.

---

**Second attempt**

I then tried to include role using `delegate_to` and `delegate_fact`:

```py
- hosts: peripheral
  gather_facts: False

  pre_tasks:

    - name: Load Configuration
      set_fact:
        peripheral_conf: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Insert values into central DB based on peripheral configuration
      include_role:
        name: '{{ item }}'
        apply:
          delegate_to: central
          delegate_facts: yes
      run_once: yes
      loop:
        - role1
        - role2

  roles:
    # insert values into peripheral DB
    - role1
    - role2
    - role3
```

but it keeps using peripheral's DB connection parameters.

---

**Working attempt**

I finally was able to make it works adding an explicit overriding of the connection parameters:

```py
- hosts: peripheral
  gather_facts: False

  pre_tasks:

    - name: Load Configuration
      set_fact:
        peripheral_conf: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Insert values into central DB based on peripheral configuration
      include_role:
        name: '{{ item }}'
        apply:
          delegate_to: central
      run_once: yes
      vars:
        db_host    : "{{ hostvars['central_app1']['db_host'] }}"
        db_database: "{{ hostvars['central_app1']['db_database'] }}"
        db_username: "{{ hostvars['central_app1']['db_username'] }}"
        db_password: "{{ hostvars['central_app1']['db_password'] }}"
      loop:
        - role1
        - role2

  roles:
    # insert values into peripheral DB
    - role1
    - role2
    - role3
```

---

**And finally, the question**

The playbook does the job but I'd like to know if this is the only way of do this or there is any better and/or more efficient way to do this.